# issue related sqlite fetching dates between dates from database IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

just few Moments before it was working perfectly and suddenly dont know what happen and havnt changed anything but its not working anymore tried so much but cant figure out what i am missing any help be like heaven for me below is my code

this is how my dates are in my sqlite datbase 
           01/20/1978

```
       01/20/2013

       02/28/1979


       MM/dd/yyyy


 NSLog(@"Fetching holidays from the database between %@ and %@...", fromDate, toDate);
// fromdate and todate both are nsdate this is what they prints 
// Fetching holidays from the database between 2013-06-29 18:30:00 +0000 and 2013-08-03 18:29:59 +0000...   
    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];



    NSString *query4 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select Birthdates,Names,Profilepic,Email,Phonenumber from PersonNamesAndBirthDates where Birthdates between ? and ?"];


    sqlite3_stmt *stmt4;
    int x4 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1,[query4 UTF8String],-1, &stmt4, nil);
    if (x4 == SQLITE_OK)
        [fmt setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt4, 1, [[fmt stringFromDate:fromDate] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt4, 2, [[fmt stringFromDate:toDate] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    //**IT WAS GOING IN WHILE BUT NOW ITS NOT GOING IN SO IT JUST JUMP FROM HERE**
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt4) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt4, 0)];
        NSString *proPic = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt4, 1)];
        NSString *email = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt4, 2)];
        NSString *pNumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt4, 3)];
        NSString *bDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt4, 4)];


        [holidays addObject:[Holiday holidayNamed:name email:email profilePic:proPic phoneNumber:pNumber date:[fmt dateFromString:bDate]]];


        NSLog(@"%@",holidays);

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt4);
    NSLog(@"%@",holidays);

    sqlite3_close(database1);
    [delegate loadedDataSource:self];
```

}

Comment: come to this iphone-ipad room here is link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatter matches what you've used in the database, but the problem is that that format will not sort dates chronologically. SQLite does not have a proper date data type and just instead stores the dates as strings (or also numbers, but not as true "date" data type). Worse, because your current string values are formatted as `MM/dd/yyyy`, it will therefore sort them alphabetically, i.e., by month, then day, then year, not chronologically.

The solution is to:

- Go through your database and replace your date values, currently stored as strings in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy`, with string values in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`.
- Likewise, in your above code sample, replace:

  ```
  [fmt setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
  ```

  with

  ```
  [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
  ```

You can also use one of the formats enumerated in [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). But pick a format such that when you sort it alphabetically, it also effectively sorts it chronologically as well.

---

While you really should fix your data in your database, you *could* define a custom SQLite function that can convert from `MM/dd/yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` on the fly. So, before your `@implementation`, declare this new function:

```
void convertFromMMDDYYYY(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv);
```

Then, after the `@end` of your `@implementation`, implement this function:

```
/*
 convert from MM/dd/yyyy
 to           yyyy-MM-dd
 */
void convertFromMMDDYYYY(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    assert(argc == 1);

    if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) != SQLITE_TEXT) {
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
        return;
    }

    NSString *originalDateString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0])];

    static NSDateFormatter *mmddyyyyFormat = nil;
    static NSDateFormatter *yyyymmddFormat = nil;

    // date formatters are a little computationally intensive to create, so let's only do it once

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        mmddyyyyFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        mmddyyyyFormat.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

        yyyymmddFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        yyyymmddFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    });

    NSDate *date = [mmddyyyyFormat dateFromString:originalDateString];
    if (date == nil)
    {
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
        return;
    }

    NSString *resultingDateString = [yyyymmddFormat stringFromDate:date];
    char *buf = sqlite3_malloc(sizeof(char) * [resultingDateString length] + 1);
    strcpy(buf, [resultingDateString UTF8String]);

    sqlite3_result_text(context, buf, -1, sqlite3_free);
}
```

Now, when your app opens the database, define a SQLite function, `YYYYMMDD`, which will call the above routine:

```
if (sqlite3_create_function_v2(database1, "YYYYMMDD", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, &convertFromMMDDYYYY, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_create_function_v2 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database1));
```

Then you can change your SQL to avail yourself of this new SQLite function:

```
NSString *query4 = @"select Birthdates,Names,Profilepic,Email,Phonenumber from PersonNamesAndBirthDates where YYYYMMDD(Birthdates) between ? and ?";
```

And, of course, since this is looking for `yyyy-MM-dd` format, you should use that format for the values you bind for the `WHERE` clause in this particular SQL statement:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt4;
int x4 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1,[query4 UTF8String],-1, &stmt4, nil);
if (x4 == SQLITE_OK) {
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    // ...
}
```

Again, it is better to fix the data, but you could use this custom function approach. It is a really inefficient way of doing it, but should work.

Comment: why i need to formate it in year month day? why cant in mm dd yyyy

Comment: i changed my formater to [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"]; not working

Comment: sir I cant not change my database dates because i have used them in my whole project if i change them there i need to changed formater in whole project any other advice before hour it was working correctly but dont know what happen now :[[

Comment: @java I know it sounds painful, but it's really the right thing to do. Your dates are simply not in the right format. If searching for ranges of dates worked before, it only did so coincidentally. Dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` format will _not_ sort correctly. Anyway, the right solution is fix the dates. Alternatively, you could write a SQLite string function that converts your dates on the fly, but that's not the right long term solution.

Comment: Sir I am in really hurry so much pressure so short-term is ok for me can you update your answer with that?

Comment: all are closing here so I need to go now I hope to see updation from you thank you so much sir for this help now on in next project I will take care of dates in right formate

Answer (score 0):

You must use one of the [supported date/time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) for comparisons to work correctly.

Comment: as you can see that i have created formater which is same as my database date